# Why React's component is "component"?

Tags: reactjs

After reading [this article](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/components-and-props.html) and writing couple of React apps I still do not understand why "component" is called component. I.e. I understand that it is "piece of code" but for me, who came from C# and Python word "encapsulation" means a lot. In React I see that creating, for example, component "UsernamePasswordComponent" that looks like:

```
class UsernamePasswordComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        <input type="text" name="username"
          value={this.props.username} onChange={this.props.handlerUsernameFromParentComponent} />
        <input type="password" name="password"
          value={this.props.password} onChange=this.props.handlerUsernameFromParentComponent />
        <button onClick={this.props.handlerClickFromParentComponent}>Login</>
      </div>
    );
}
```

And I forced to store `password` and `username` in parent (usually root) state and I have to write a lot of garbage in PARENT component to handle children's change event. I do not understand.

So finally I have following questions:

1. Why React provides so ugly method of two-way binding? I like `LinkedStateMixin` but it is marked as "deprecated". Why???
2. Why I have to store `paswword` and `username` in parent's state instead of encapsulate it inside subcomponent and provide kind of interface to get data from it. Or this component can be rewritten in more react-way and encapsulates everything?

Comment: 1) In the React world two-way data-binding is more or less frowned upon. A uniform data-flow is easier to reason about for complex apps.
2) React components can usually be put into the presentation category (only display stuff) and container category. It is always a good idea to separate design from business logic.

Comment: I think you missed the point about the React architecture. What you should be actually using is the flux architecture, or its simpler version called redux. That will allow you to completely separate state from you components.

Answer (score 0):

You would store the `password` and `username` field inside the component. Because everything related to that handling is *inside* the component. The parent does not care. The parent only wants the results of the credentials.

In your case you have a simple component, but there are way more complex structures for example an entire Table. You don't want to handle the Table states in your parent since you don't care. You only want to pass the `dataSource` to the `TableComponent` and let it handle there.

And defining callbacks is perfectly fine - so you actually get what you want.